# Multiple figure to continue on the next page

Tags: table-of-contents

Because I have to use many figures in one I need to let the figure continue next page. I used the following command:

```
\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{figure}%
\begin{longtable}{@{}cc@{}}
  \caption{Exchange market pressure and crises threshold \label{fig: empall}}
\endhead

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{argentina} &
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{australia}\\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{belarus} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{bolivia} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{brazil} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{chile} \\


\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{colombia} &
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{costarica} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{denmark} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{georgia} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{iceland} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{indonesia} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{japan} &
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{korea} \\


\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{malaysia} &   
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{mexico} \\


\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{newzealand} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{norway} \\


\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{papuanewguinea} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{paraguay} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{peru} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{philippines} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{russia} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{singapore} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{sweden} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{switzerland} \\ 

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{thailand} &
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{turkey} \\

\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{ukraine} & 
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{uk} \\


\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{uruguay}}
\end{longtable}
```

But this creates one problem. I have the name of the figures in each page and instead want to have continued from previous page. Furthermore, this creates another problem in the figure list I have the name of figure 3 times.

[image]

I instead want to have something like:

name of figure 40-43

So, instead of multiple name, to have just one and then number of page, i.e. 1-4.

Comment: Inside of a longtable you can add two types of captions. One for the first page, another for all following pages. Take a look at the difference of endhead and endfirsthead.

Comment: Can you give me one example how can I do that? But I think the long table would put the figure in the table list instead of figure list, which would solve one problem but create another one.

Comment: Solution for your problem you can find answer to your previous question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524478/xltabular-as-table. Just use `longtable` instead of `xltabular`.

Comment: Here I am using longtable but it creates the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Please prepare a complete minimal working example.

Comment: @Arbnor, but the principle is the same. As I told you, instead `\begin{xltabular}{l X}` use `\begin{longtable}{@{}cc@{}}`. AL other is the same. However, more important is: how you will know, what present some picture?

Comment: This is really weird because you *don't* need a table at all. It seems you need *one* caption for the whole bunch of figures. In such a case, you can try and insert a caption for all of them, I guess outside of a figure environment.

Comment: `\begin{longtable}{@{}cc@{}}
  \caption{Exchange market pressure and crises threshold \label{fig: empall}}
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Exchange market pressure and crises threshold - continued from previous page}
\endhead` might give you something cloder to your desired result.

Comment: First, be aware that figures should freely float on the text and don't now exactly when the figure begins and where it ends. Second, can someone give an exact code how to do that because I am new user of Latex and can't get it?